# Celery - intentionally fail a task (do not log the error)

Tags: python, celery

I have a chain of tasks. I want to interrupt it as soon as a task "fails" - I mean failing in terms of my logic (not in terms of celery).

An example of this could be compiling the code (task 1) and then running the compiled output (task 2). It has no sense to run the code if the compilation failed.

Sure, I could raise an exception from the first task. That does the job pretty well, but the problem is that my exception is logged as a regular error in celery. I do not like this behavior as it will mingle with real programming errors.

I hope it makes sense and I am looking forward to anyone's help!